# can someone resolve the precedence of following expression?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

can some one give me the  precedence **abstract syntax tree of a[++b] and ++a[b]** so that i can better understand i am having difficulty in having order of evaluation of operator..i get tht **expression evaluation has nothing to do with order of evaluation of operators..!!** in this case  that in array[expr1] expr1( sub script expression) any operator in expr1 is should be evaluated first? i am simply sayin that in a[++b]...[] has higher precedence than ++(prefix) so i look at the expression a[++b] and think **b is involved in two operators in which the higher prec. [] should be evaluated first**.
but someone tell me where i am wrong?
  **

```
 int main(){
     int a[4]={1,2,3,4};, b=1;
     printf("%d ",a[b++]);
     b=1;
      printf("%d",++a[b]);
           }
```

**

Comment: show us some code, in C **something[value]** is used to access an array position, is **a (a[++b])** an array ?

Comment: What do you want to say? Any way as [] has higher precedence the ++b under it will evaluate i.e `b=b+1;`.

Comment: @PHIfounder how ++(prefix) can evaluate before [] since both operators on b

Comment: @DurgeshK.Singh its not evaluated before,its evaluated after [] i.e what's inside [] is evaluated first.

Comment: @PHIfounder Precedence has very little to do with order of evaluation.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Actually this even confuses me too, just consider : `b=0;arr[++b];' here I don't understand if precedence has little to do  with order of evaluation then why does it evaluate to `arr[1];`.

Comment: @PHIfounder `++b` evaluates to `b + 1`. This is the value of the expression. It also schedules variable `b` to be incremented. The assignment to `b` will occur at some point before the next sequence point, but the time it occurs has nothing to do with the precedence of `[]` or any other operator. In `f()[++b]`, variable `b` can be incremented either before or after `f()` is called. This is *unspecified*. In some other circumstances, e.g. `(b++) + (--b)`, combining assignments to `b` make the program *undefined behavior*. Little of all this has to do with precedence.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Whoa ... learning C is like memorizing whole bible or any religious book. Thanks for the explanation,will go through more on this one.thanks once again.

Comment: @PHIfounder The C standards leave these aspects as little specified as possible for two reasons: 1) the standards should ideally accommodate various pre-existing C compilers, so that they turn out to be already standard-compliant, and 2) this gives more opportunities for a given compiler to generate efficient code for the assembly language it targets. In the case of `f()[++b]`, of course the value `b + 1` must be computed before the memory access can take place, but the compiler can choose whether to write back this new value to `b` before or after calling `f()`, whichever seems most efficient

Comment: @PHIfounder i think a[expr] means (*(a+(expr))) hence Any operator in expr is evaluated frst then + and then * after that any else ..and ofcourse lvalue are converted to rvalues before...

Answer (score 1):

There are no sequence points when evaluating a parameter list. So the only thing you can guarantee about that is that at some point before printf is called, `b` will be incremented as a side effect of the postincrement. This isn't an order of precedence issue at all.

That answer applied to your original code,

```
printf("%d ",a[b++], ++a[b]);
```

which I see you have now changed completely.

Comment: Not even the above mentioned thing is guaranteed, because _If a side effect on a scalar object is unsequenced relative to either a different side effect on the same scalar object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar object, the behavior is undefined._ [ISO/IEC 9899]

Comment: he only invokes the side effect once

Comment: And he is _using the value of the same scalar object_, so, _the behavior is undefined._

Comment: oh, right, I thought you were talking about the increment. Yes, I realised the behaviour was undefined wrt the value of b at any point

Answer (score 0):

In your example `a[++b]`, `b` is not an operand of `[]`; `[]` has two Operands, the one in front of `[` and the one between `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please try to understand meaning of `++`. `a++` means `a=a+1`. Now difference between `a++` and `++a` (before and after):

> `a++`will be executed after completion of statement i.e (after next;
>   or line usually) where `++a` will be executed immediately.

Now come to your point in `a[b++]` `++` is working on array index `b` where in `a[b]++` is working in bth value. `a[++b]` and `++a[b]` are increasing the value immediately before another calculation.